# Trouble setting 4 monitors with 2 Ndivia GPUs

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xserver

I am having troubles setting up Quad monitors.

1. I had 2 identical GPUs (geforce gtx 750 Ti) and 4 identical monitors.
2. After installing Ubuntu 14.04, nvidia driver(`NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.72.run`) installed.
3. From Ubuntu Software Center, found 'NVIDIA X Server Settings' and installed.
4. Tried to layout 4 monitors via 'NVIDIA X Server settings', but it seems only 2 monitors work while other 2 monitors are shown as 'disabled'.
5. Here is my `xrandr` output

   ```
   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
   DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
      1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
      1680x1050      60.0  
      1600x900       60.0  
      1440x900       59.9  
      1400x1050      60.0  
      1280x1024      60.0  
      1280x800       59.8  
      1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
      1152x864       60.0  
      1024x768       60.0  
      800x600        60.3  
      720x576        50.0  
      720x480        59.9  
      640x480        59.9     59.9  
   HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
      1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
      1680x1050      60.0  
      1600x900       60.0  
      1440x900       59.9  
      1400x1050      60.0  
      1280x1024      60.0  
      1280x800       59.8  
      1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
      1152x864       60.0  
      1024x768       60.0  
      800x600        60.3  
      720x576        50.0  
      720x480        59.9  
      640x480        59.9     59.9  
   DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   yhju@yhju:/etc/X11$
   ```

I have tried a lot of things including reinstalling UBUNTU consequently, and
**it seems Ubuntu is not capable of setting two GPU(2 of Geforce GTX 750 Ti)s in order to use 4 monitors (connecting 2 monitors for each one of GPUs).

If you know solution to this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Can you verify that linux sees 4 monitor devices?

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the output of `xrandr`

Comment: I am not sure if linux support 4 monitors, i am just trying to set quad monitors working.

Comment: Well, `xrandr` is showing you only have two monitors connected at `HDMI-0` and `HDMI-1`.  Are you sure there aren't any connection problems? Try connecting a single monitor at `DVI-I-0` and see if `xrandr` will list it.

Comment: yes David, I have 2 identical GPUs and connected 2 monitors via HDMI for each GPUs.  However, it seems Ubuntu OS does not recognize second GPUs . I will look for a way to set 2 gpus on Ubuntu. Or, if anyone knows "How to set 2 GPUs on one System, please let me know."   Thanks.